# UIImageView blinking animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, viewdidload

I am trying to make a `UIImageView` blink upon `viewDidLoad`. I am not sure what the best way to do this is. I've tried using loops with `.hidden=YES` and `.hidden=NO` but this seems like a bad way to do this. I need some proper advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have just want to hide and show then use NStimer For that purpose
something like this

in .h file add this property
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

```
- (void)onTimerEvent:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    self.imageView.hidden = !self.imageView.hidden;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

**Swift**:

```
func onTimerEvent(timer: Timer) {
    self.imageView.isHidden = !self.imageView.isHidden
}

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerEvent(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

But UIImageView can animate different images as well
something like this

```
self.iamgeView.animationImages = <arrayOfImages>
self.imageView.duration = <duration>
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error message saying: Property "timer" not found on object of type 'DemoViewController *'

Comment: you need to add NStimer *timer as property in demoViewController.h

Comment: Thanks brother, i'll check it very soon. I have a one more question that is below the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261851/get-yahoo-contact-list

Answer (score 8):

try this :

```
-(void)blink:(UIView*)view count:(int) count
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

        view.alpha = 0.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

            view.alpha = 1.0;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

            [self blink:view count:count-1];

        }];


    }];
}
```

or if you want it to blink forever try this :

```
-(void)blinkForever:(UIView*)view
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

        view.alpha = 0.0;

    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I love this solution. I have a question though. How do I make it blink to black instead of whatever is in the background? Setting alpha to 0 just makes it transparent and shows the image that is in this view's background. I tried passing in a UIImage view whose background color is black but that didn't help. I even tried setting that view's image to a black image but that wouldn't animate. Any ideas?

Comment: You can put the blinking view inside another super view whose background is black, but the blinking view should be completely opaque when its alpha is equal to 1.0, otherwise the black background will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use alpha of your UIImageView. Here is an example (simply call `startAnim` in your `viewDidLoad`):

```
static NSInteger count = 0;
static NSInteger maxBlind = 10;

- (void)startAnim{

    CGFloat animDuration = 0.5f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animDuration
                     animations:^{
                         self.myImageView.alpha = 0.f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:animDuration
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.myImageView.alpha = 1.f;
                                          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              if (count < maxBlind){
                                                  [self startAnim];
                                                  count++;
                                              }
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: The above is good, thank you, but missing one line.  You need to remove the imageView in the second completion block or it will stay in place obscuring the fade in/fade out:  

                                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              if (count < maxBlind){
                                              [myImageView removeFromSuperview];  // here
                                                  [self startAnim];
                                                  count++;
                                              }

Answer (score 1):

Use UIImageView animation, you could just put in an empty image or a blank image:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/27/animate-images-uiimageview-completion-handler/

Enjoy